# как сделать вход для телеграмм бота написанного на telebot и все данные при регистрации вводятся в sql

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite

есть регистрация условного пользователя с помощью библиотеки sqlite3 и в формате sql,
при регистрации создается 3 столбца id name password. как сделать проверку зарегистрирован пользователь или нет, если такой id существует в списке то вход по имени и паролю

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def  start(message):
    conn=sqlite3.connect('baz.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('create table if not exists users(id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(50), pass varchar(50))')
    conn.commit()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'запрос на регистрацию выполняется. Введите ваше имя')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name)

def user_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text.split()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'придумайте пароль')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_pass)
def user_pass(message):
    password = message.text.split()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('baz.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('insert into users (name, pass) values ("%s","%s")' % (name, password))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```